# SQL Server: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" - on identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am inserting data into a table with an identity column called `unique_id`. I am leaving the `unique_id` column out of the insert, assuming that the value will then be seeded from the identity configuration on the column.

`Insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2, column_3, processed_dt)
VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C', GETDATE());
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'unique_id', table 'db.dbo.table_name'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

When I double click on the `unique_id` column in SQL Server Management Studio, I see that the following values are set:

- Identity: true
- Identity Seed: 1
- Identity Increment: 1

What other configuration may be wrong to cause the identity seed to not be used automatically?

**UPDATE:**

Based on some of the recommendations I am seeing, I want to add that this schema was converted by our vendor from Oracle into SQL Server. I'm guessing that part of that process must of included converting Oracle `Sequences` into SQL Server `Identity` columns. Something being "broken" with the identity column is certainly a possibility.

I'm definitely on the correct database, table, and column. The `Identity` on this column was not created today, it was created weeks ago.

Is there any configuration the vendor could have put in place that would disable the auto assignment of the seed value and force the developer to "fetch" the next seed value manually?

Comment: Looks like the designer must be telling you wrong information. Either outdated as definition has changed externally since it was opened or you made unsaved changes, or you are looking at the wrong object. The column can't have identity set.

Comment: Or remote possibility that code in a trigger that sets `identity insert` to on and inserts an explicit null might cause this I suppose.

Comment: What @MartinSmith said. Either some subtle mistake, or an unlikely combination of unusual database artifacts/events.

Comment: Use Profiler to trace the exact SQL statements being executed. They might not be what you expect. And make sure you are looking at the right table/db/server.

Comment: Can you check what this returns `Select ident_seed('table_name'), ident_incr('table_name')`?

Comment: I tried using the profiler, it traced my query, but gave no usable feedback to what the issue was. As a matter of fact, the profiler didn't even report that an error occurred. I did still receive the error in sql studio. I tried using the following command to turn on/off the auto population from the identity seed, allowing for manual specification of the id number: SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON. This gave an error that the column did not have an identity. I will drop the column and recreate it.

Comment: Have SQL Server Management Studio generate a `CREATE` script for your table. Then post this script here. Perhaps the script will show to you or someone else here what is wrong with your identity column.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores the seed/nextID value to be used.  I'm wondering if the conversion from Oracle neglected to set that value.  Try using the the following command on that table to check what it's seed value is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, NORESEED )
```

Maybe it actually is null, which is causing the error.  Then you can use a variation of the same command to 'reseed' or set the next value to be used.

For more information and options:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I was lead here when one of my developers had this very issue and wanted to share what caused/fixed it for us.

Basically, on another tab in SQL server "Edit Top 200 Rows" was open for the specified table.

Once this tab was closed, the insert worked without issue.

Hope this helps someone!